# Unfortunately we were unable to process the request. Please try again

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-plus

I'm trying to integrate Paypal Plus to my store, using API Reference guide (see the screenshot). Everything is done but the paypal returns 500 error when I try to complete the checkout: UNKNOWN_INTERNAL_ERROR.

Searching through Google wasn't successful.

[image]

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplusdcc/ppplusdcc.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="ppplusDiv" style="width: 300px; height: 502px;"></div>
<script type="application/javascript">
var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
    "approvalUrl": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-25D26051FW287782J",
    "placeholder": "ppplusDiv",
    "mode": "sandbox",
    "payerFirstName": "John",
    "payerLastName": "Doe",
    "payerPhone": "33927349232",
    "payerEmail": "admin@example.com",
                "payerTaxId": "831.899.557-00",
        "payerTaxIdType": "BR_CPF",
            "disableContinue": "continueButton",
    "enableContinue": "continueButton",
    "language": "en_US",
    "country": "BR",
});
```

```
<button id="continueButton" class="ty-btn__big ty-btn__primary cm-ajax cm-checkout-place-order ty-btn" type="submit" name="dispatch[checkout.place_order]" onclick="if (!document.getElementById('product_agreements') || document.getElementById('product_agreements').checked) { ppp.doContinue(); return false;}">Разместить заказ</button>
```

Comment: You should provide more details (and also the mentioned screenshot).

Comment: I hope that is a test credit card number `:-)`